# My function accidentally removes numbers from string

Tags: php, arrays, string, substring

My function accidentally removes numbers from my string by I want that they still remain. How can I change it?

The original string that must be invariated;
iPhone 7 plus 34 GB 10 inches

```
echo implode(' ',array_unique(str_word_count('iPhone 7 plus 34 GB 10 inches',1)));
```

Unfortunately, it returns:
iPhone plus GB inches

Comment: I don't understand your question. That is the whole purpose of `str_word_count()`, it returns only words. If you want to white list numbers as possible letters in a work then use the 3rd parameter. e.g. `, implode('', range(0,9))` or something similar

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add 0..9 at the char list as per syntax,

```
echo implode(' ',array_unique(str_word_count('iPhone 7 plus 34 GB 10 inches',1,"0..9")));
```

[**Working demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e456f20bb1a2248ba43f73b0f9aae6422bf475d1).

**Syntax**

```
str_word_count ( string $string [, int $format = 0 [, string $charlist ]] ) : mixed
```